# How to change the logistic regression output in R

Tags: r, coefficients

this is my first question so i give my very best do describe it as good as possible. For a project i want to use logistic regression models and show the results in some graphs. At the moment i have the following problem: When i create my logistic model with the following code:

```
m3<- glm(alive ~ seatbelt*dvcat + sex + ageOFocc + airbag, family = binomial, data = nassCDS)
summary(m3)
```

the output looks like this:

[image]

alive is a binary variable with 1 for alive and 0 for dead.
seatbelt is a factor with the levels seatbelted and none.
sex is male or female.
ageOFocc is the age of the driver.
airbag is a factor with the levels airbag or none.
dvcat is a factor with 5 levels representing the impact speed of the vehicle.

Because i am not that proficient with R I wanted to recreate the steps on a website i found. So i basically copied their code and expected the same output. But there are tiny differences. The Output from the website showed the coefficients with "Seatbeltseatbelted" and "airbagairbag" whereas my output shows the values for "seatbeltnone" and "airbagnone" (marked yellow on the picture). Can i change this?

I already testet it on a different computer and had the same problem. A friend of mine tried it on hers and she got the "correct" output. I Reinstalled  R and R Studio and reinstalled Windows on my PC, but nothing seems to work for me.

I hope you can help me :) Kind regards Jan

Comment: Your `seatbelt` and `airgbag` variables are `factor` and show the result cpmpared to their reference level. However, this actually might be the right result, compared to your source! Anyway, you may want to use `?as.numeric()` to convert the factors.

Comment: @Dave2e `glm()` can take character columns as input, so converting columns from characters to factors might not be necessary.

Comment: @Dave2e i am using R 3.5.3

Comment: @DarrenTsai, Correct, glm can take character columns but the question is why is the output different between the example and the current output.  I suspect it is a difference between character and factor, given the limited information provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be that you mess up the ***reference levels*** of `seatbelt` and `airgbag`. Try to use `relevel()` to reset their reference levels to `none`, and run `glm()` again.

```
nassCDS$seatbelt <- relevel(nassCDS$seatbelt, ref = "none")
nassCDS$airbag <- relevel(nassCDS$airgbag, ref = "none")
```

---

Theoretically, those functions like `lm()` and `glm()` take the first level of a factor as its reference level, and levels of a factor are sorted alphabetically by default. Therefore, if a factor contains two levels, e.g. `airbag` and `none`, then `airbag` will be treated as its reference level. `relevel()` can move the level you set in the `ref` argument to the first position, and therefore the model will treat it as reference.